# Member Function returns wrong smart pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm creating a very simple game engine using modern `C++` in the style of old text-based adventures.

I have a Room class like this:

```
class Room
{
public:
    Room(void);
    void connect(shared_ptr<Room> room, Direction direction);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Room> north;
    std::shared_ptr<Room> south;
    std::shared_ptr<Room> east;
    std::shared_ptr<Room> west;
};
```

`connect()` is basically a setter for the `north`, `south`, etc. pointers.
It looks like this:

```
void Room::connect(std::shared_ptr<Room> room, Direction direction)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case Direction::NORTH:
            this->north = room;
            break;
        case Direction::SOUTH:
            this->south = room;
            break;
        case Direction::EAST:
            this->east = room;
            break;
        case Direction::WEST:
            this->west = room;
            break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "[ERROR] Invalid direction" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now I can call

```
Room example_room{};
Room another_room{};

example_room.connect(std::make_shared<Room>(another_room), Direction::NORTH)
another_room.connect(std::make_shared<Room>(example_room), Direction::SOUTH)
```

When I boot up `lldb` and look at the variables, `example_room::north` will be a `std::shared_ptr<Room>` pointing to a `Room` object, however, this object doesn't seem to be `another_room`, because its `south` data member is a `std::shared_ptr` containing a `nullptr`.

So they point to other Rooms, but they don't point at each other. I know the reason must be somewhere in the `connect()` member function, but I don't know where.

Comment: Using make_shared for stack objects is wrong

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux it will call a copy constructor, won't it ?

Comment: Making circular dependences with shared_ptr is not a good idea

Comment: In general: if you have a shared pointer to an object, then you can *only* have shared pointers, weak pointers and normal pointers to that object. You can't store the object itself in a variable or array, for example, and you can't have a unique pointer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_shared` creates a new object from the arguments that it's called with and returns a `shared_ptr` that points to the new object. In the example code it makes **copies** of the two original rooms. That's not what's needed here. In fact, shared pointers are just wrong in this application. There will be several rooms that belong to the application, and they should be defined globally or in some sort of container that manages their lifetimes. Each room should have an ordinary pointer to its neighbors. There's no need for any room to manage the lifetime of its neighbors. That's the responsibility of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `example_room` and `another_room` instances on the stack but  to `connect()` you pass entirely new instances created on the heap with `make_shared()`. Making your `example_room` and `another_room` be `shared_ptr` would work **but!** As @PiotrSkotnicki has mentioned in the comment you shouldn't use `shared_ptr` for circular dependences. Use `weak_ptr` for `Room` members instead.

e.g.:

```
class Room
{
public:
    // ...
    void connect(weak_ptr<Room> room, Direction direction);
private:
    std::weak_ptr<Room> north;
    std::weak_ptr<Room> south;
    // ...
}
```

then:

```
auto example_room = std::make_shared<Room>();
auto another_room = std::make_shared<Room>();

example_room->connect(another_room, Direction::NORTH)
another_room->connect(example_room, Direction::SOUTH)
```

Just make sure you keep original `shared_ptr`s alive as long as you need these links.